# Laravel 5.1 group routes for specific domains and all subdomains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a project with multiple domains pointing to it. Now I want to group routes by domains and subdomains.

For example I want to have separate routes for example.com and every subdomain of example.com

I do this right now like this:

```
$RoutesOnlyForExamp = function() {
  Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'TestController@home']);
};

Route::group(['domain' => 'sub1.example.com'], $RoutesOnlyForExamp);
Route::group(['domain' => 'sub2.example.com'], $RoutesOnlyForExamp);
Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com'], $RoutesOnlyForExamp);
```

The home() method would give me this:

```
return view('home')
```

Now I have a weired problem. I have some links in my view which all lead into a

```
return view('RANDOM_VIEW');
```

like the home() method.

The links in the view are generated like this:

```
<a href="{{route('ROUTENAME')}}">LINKNAME</a>
```

Now let's say I access the site via sub1.example.com. Now some of my links look right, like this:

```
<a href="sub1.example.com/slug">Random Link 1</a>
```

But some look like this, which is wrong because I am on sub1.example.com and not example.com:

```
<a href="example.com/slug">Random Link 1</a>
```

And I don't see any pattern when and why it takes the wrong domain. My goal is that if I access the site via sub1.example.com all links should take this and not just example.com.

I hope the problem is clear. Otherwise I can try it with more detail.

I appreciate any help and thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you use to generate the links? An what is the route definition you use?

Comment: @milo526 I updated my question with the information, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can accept the subdomain name like

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'], $RoutesOnlyForExamp);
```

and have it available as a variable and route parameter.

When you want to generate a link to a subdomain route you can do `route('ROUTENAME', [$subdomain])`.

Your main website routes are going to work as expected if declared like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com'], $RoutesOnlyForExamp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My question here would be what if I generate the link like route('ROUTENAME', [$subdomain]) but access the site via example.com, will the $subdomain part beeing ignored?

Comment: If your *ROUTENAME* is declared with domain `{subdomain}.example.com` and you access example.com it won't get triggered.

Comment: The thing is I want to use my routegroup for both the main domain and sub domains. The reason for this is that I've got a staging branch and a production branch. I do not want to have different routes in them to have them changed manually. So I need a solution which works for both main and subdomains. Like if you access the site with example.com the url of the link will be example.com/link and via sub1.example.com the same link would be sub1.example.com/link. Is this going to work with your solution? Thank you very much

Comment: To generate a link with the `route()` function to any route which is on subdomain `{subdomain}.example.com` you have to give it a parameter the subdomain `route('ROUTENAME', [$subdomain])` otherwise the generated link will be to example.com and not the subdomain.

Comment: I tested it and if I write Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'], $RoutesOnlyForExamp); for every subdomain, all subdomains don't even go inside the group so that the routing is not working at all :/

Comment: Remember that `{subdomain}` is a dynamic route parameter so you have to pass it to the route links you generate.